# Cannot find a version of 'io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom' that satisfies the version constraints ,getting this error when i use my custom package

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus

Execution failed for task ':quarkusGenerateCode'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':quarkusDependency'.
> Could not resolve io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom:2.7.2.Final.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Cannot find a version of 'io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-bom' that satisfies the version constraints:

Build successful expected

Comment: What does your `build.gradle` look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.